# How to say soaking meat in sauce for flavor?

Tags: word-request

When cooking, there is a pre-process of meat. One soaks meat in sauce, wait for flavor going into meat, then finally cooks it. How to say the process of soaking meat in source in order to add flavor? Thank you. [image]

Comment: Google is your friend. [soak meat in source](https://www.google.com/search?q=soak+meat+in+source&oq=soak+meat+in+source&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.3983j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Do you possibly mean "sauce" rather than "source"?

Comment: A **marinade** is the noun; **marinate** is the verb

Comment: Thank you for all your comment for google search by myself. In fact, I did that and c found some difintion. But, the problem is that I cannot tell if it is a rarely-used, only-used-by-professional-user, only-used-at-some-local-part-in-the-world, or a slang better not be used at official words. These are something you cannot easily find answers on google. And, I believe this is the value of this site.

Comment: You do learn some second language such as Spanish right? Now you write an article with the language, and with all the tools you can get. Google, internet, dictionary, whatever. Then, A native speaker gives you a revise. No matter how hard you try, you still make mistakes and can be corrected a lot. These mistakes are the above mentioned. If it is a rarely-used, only-used-by-professional-user, only-used-at-some-local-part-in-the-world, or a slang better not be used at official words. Because a native speaker can tell you that, but google and dictionary cannot. I think closing it is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you call it in your language?

If you were Chinese and you called this process "腌泡" then [a bilingual dictionary search](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/chinese-english/%E8%85%8C%E6%B3%A1) would find the English word "marinade", and the verb form "to marinate" or "to marinade".

An English dictionary can confirm that **marinate** means "allow a sauce or flavouring mixture to absorb into something".

The process is similar if your language isn't Chinese.